# Scipy clustering; use the physics Minkowski metric?

Tags: python, scipy

So this morning I learnt that the Minkowski metric does not always mean;

[image: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinkowskiMetric.html]
See [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinkowskiMetric.html) for details.

Apparently in scipy it is just a p-norm. Scipy has an option to weight the p-norm, but only with positive weights, so that cannot achieve the relativistic Minkowski metric.

I would like to do hierarchical clustering on points in relativistic 4 dimensional space. For two points;

`a = [a_time, a_x, a_y, a_z]`

`b = [b_time, b_x, b_y, b_z]`

The distance between them should be;

`invarient_s(a, b) = sqrt(-(a_time-b_time)^2 + (a_x-b_x)^2 + (a_y-b_y)^2 + (a_z-b_z)^2)`

I'm working in python and ideally using scipy's [fcluster](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster). Before I go and write my own clustering is there anyway to get this metric in fcluster? Can I add to the list of available metrics?

Edit; it appears only [fclusterdata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata.html) supports metrics in the first place.

Comment: Does Minkowski (rather than p-norm) not support negative weights? That would be surprising.

Comment: @AndrasDeak sadly not; `ValueError: Input weights should be all non-negative`

Comment: Wow. Good catch. There _has_ to be a straightforward alternative, otherwise this is a huge problem. I suspect the problem is that negative weights don't give you a proper metric. I'll try to look into it later.

Comment: The only issue I could find is https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7953 where positive weights are assumed. Wonder if something like astropy has an alternative (of course you can always just write a distance function by hand and accelerate it with numba).

Comment: Anyway I just noticed your actual question (sorry) and it doesn't even seem that fcluster supports multiple metrics...

Comment: @AndrasDeak, thanks; here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.minkowski.html is the page for it. I guess scipy doesn't want to return complex numbers for time like distances? I'm pretty confident everything in my set is space like.

Comment: oops sorry https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata.html this supports metrics

Comment: Yeah, you don't even want non-equal vectors to have zero distance, let alone negative or complex. I'm not familiar with clustering and fcluster; doesn't distance calculation come _before_ fcluster? The docs example calls pdist to get an input, where you could sneak in a custom metric. Edit: OK, fclusterdata explains it.

Comment: [`linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage) accepts functions as metrics just like pdist, so perhaps the docs of fclusterdata are buggy and you can pass a custom callable, not just a string. It would make sense to me from a design perspective.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thank you for pointing out that pdist is called separately, I didn't spot that. It wouldn't bee to difficult to replace that part and that is probably the solution to use.

Comment: This seems like a doc bug in fclusterdata: it just [passes the metric to pdist](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py#L2693). I can fix the docs if I get to check that I'm right about all this :) This means you should be able to pass your custom metric function (a callable) to fclusterdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news is that indeed built-in metrics (and especially the one named Minkowski) don't support negative weights. I suspect the reason for this is that in a proper metric you can only have `d(x,y) = 0` if and only if `x = y`, which is violated by the Minkowski metric. This is probably the reason for the lack of support for negative weights in any of the weighted metrics in `scipy`, see also remarks in [this github thread](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7953).

The good news is that the documentation of [`scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata.html) is buggy ([now fixed in master](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/11311)), because it claimed

```
metric: str, optional

    The distance metric for calculating pairwise distances.
    See distance.pdist for descriptions and linkage to verify
    compatibility with the linkage method.
```

Whereas the actual [implementation of `fclusterdata`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py#L2693) simply passes the `metric` input parameter along to [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist), which allows custom callables to be passed as `metric`:

```
metric: str or function, optional
```

Sure enough, we can define our own Minkowski metric function and pass that on to `fclusterdata`, but we have to make sure that all the points are spatially separated, otherwise we get complex distances and `pdist` will loudly fail (complaining about "finite" data, because `np.sqrt` when given a negative number will return `nan`, and `nan` fails the `np.isfinite` check in [`linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage)). With this reasonable caveat something like the following works:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fclusterdata 
from numpy.random import default_rng  # only for dummy data 

# generate random data, use new random machinery for best practices 
N = 10 
rng = default_rng() 
X = rng.random((N, 4)) * [0.01, 1, 1, 1]  # make them all space-like 

def physical_minkowski(v1, v2): 
    """Return the proper Minkowski metric for 4-vectors with signature -+++"""
    return np.sqrt(([-1, 1, 1, 1] * v1).dot(v2)) 

fclusterdata(X, t=1, metric=physical_minkowski)                               
# returns uninteresting array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Since the above function might get called a lot of times, it might make sense to compile it with `numba.njit` for improved performance. It only needs a small change to make that possible:

```
import numba

@numba.njit 
def jitted_minkowski(v1, v2): 
    return np.sqrt((np.array([-1, 1, 1, 1]) * v1).dot(v2))
```

I timed both of the above metric functions using IPython's built-in `%timeit` magic with `N = 1000` for a reasonable comparison:

```
>>> %timeit scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(X, metric=physical_minkowski)
... %timeit scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(X, metric=jitted_minkowski)
2.2 s ± 90.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
385 ms ± 12.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

This means that for larger sets of 4-vectors the JIT-compiled version is 5 times faster, and compilation only has to be done once (you can even cache the compiled function on disk so that you don't have to compile it each time you run your script).